# MySQL query not working on Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Where i'am doing wrong ? i want to get the records that have 
 1. No "br." in the value in column "POS_AddressLine" and
 2. POS_AddressLineNumber is NULL

Unfortenately I'm not getting the expected result.

```
SELECT POS_AddressLine, POS_AddressLineNumber
FROM SKOPJE 
WHERE (POS_AddressLine NOT LIKE '%br.%') OR
      (POS_AddressLineNumber IS NULL)
```

[SQL Result ScreenShot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fVfu.jpg)

FYI: MySQL Instance version on Amazon RDS: MySQL 5.7.11, also using My WorkBench Ver. 6.3 also tried with HeidiSQL 9.4-same result :(

Comment: Did you say  have "br." in the value,  and then use "NOT LIKE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *both* conditions, then use `AND`:

```
SELECT POS_AddressLine, POS_AddressLineNumber
FROM SKOPJE 
WHERE (POS_AddressLine NOT LIKE '%br.%') AND
      (POS_AddressLineNumber IS NULL);
```

Note that `NULL` fails `NOT LIKE`.  So, you might want:

```
SELECT POS_AddressLine, POS_AddressLineNumber
FROM SKOPJE 
WHERE (POS_AddressLine NOT LIKE '%br.%' OR POS_AddressLine IS NULL) AND
      (POS_AddressLineNumber IS NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the fast answer ! I must admit that i have a wrong logic with the data and my question was not wright. But also to mention that it is a valuable information that you have gave me that NULL fails on NOT LIKE 
anyway. You helped me figure out the other part. 
Thanks again